# nested unordered_maps in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, hashtable, unordered-map, zorba

I'm in the process of re-writting a program I have in Java to C++. I am having a lot of trouble with the complex data structure I am using:

```
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >
```

It took me a while but I was eventually able to figure out how to add 'items' (for lack of a better word) to the unordered_map. However, I come to you because I cannot figure out how to retrieve the items that I put in it using unordered_map::find.

My code is below:

```
/*
* QueryDDex.cpp
*
*  Created on: Aug 13, 2013
*      Author: Zach Graceffa
*/

#include <zorba/store_manager.h>
#include <zorba/xquery_exception.h>
#include <zorba/zorba.h>
#include <zorba/iterator.h>
#include <zorba/xquery.h>
#include <zorba/item.h>

#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace zorba;
using namespace std;
using namespace tr1;

void runQuery (char * inFile) throw(ZorbaException)
{
//create return variable
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > > nodeContainer;

//open file
ifstream myFile;
const char * ext = ".xq";
myFile.open(strcat(inFile, ext), ifstream::in);

//Instantiate the Zorba Object
void* lStore = zorba::StoreManager::getStore();
Zorba* lZorba = Zorba::getInstance(lStore);

//Feed file into string
string line;
string xqDoc;

if (myFile.is_open())
{
    while (myFile.good())
    {
      getline (myFile, line);
      xqDoc += (line + "\n");
    }
    myFile.close();
}
else
    xqDoc = "err";

//Compile the Query
XQuery_t lQuery = lZorba->compileQuery(xqDoc);

//Create an Iterator and open it so it can be used
Iterator_t parentIterator = lQuery->iterator();
parentIterator->open();

//Create an empty Item for future use
Item lItem;

while (parentIterator->next(lItem))
{
    //Create an iterator to iterate over all the child nodes that belong to the parent
    Iterator_t childIterator = lItem.getChildren();

    //Open the iterator for future use
    childIterator->open();

    //Create an empty item, which will be used to store the child nodes.
    Item child;

    //Select the first child node
    while(childIterator->next(child)){
        unordered_map<string, list<string> > childOne;

        Iterator_t grandChildIterator = child.getChildren();
        grandChildIterator->open();

        Item grandChild;

        //Create an empty item to hold the section tag name.
        Item sectionName;
        child.getNodeName(sectionName);
        nodeContainer.insert(pair<string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >(sectionName.getStringValue(), childOne));

        while(grandChildIterator->next(grandChild)){

            list<string> grandChildren;

            //Create an empty Item to hold the contents of tag name
            Item tagName;

            //Put the tag name in variable tagName
            grandChild.getNodeName(tagName);

            unordered_map<string, list<string> > temp;

            unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >::const_iterator got = nodeContainer.find(sectionName.getStringValue());

            if (temp.key_eq(tagName.getStringValue())){
                list<string> s = temp.find(tagName.getStringValue());
                s.insert(grandChild.getStringValue());
                temp.put(sectionName.getStringValue(), s);
                }else{
                    grandChildren.add(grandChild.getStringValue());
                    temp.insert(tagName.getStringValue(), grandChildren);
                }
            nodeContainer.insert(pair<string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >(sectionName.getStringValue(), temp));

            //Release any memory consumed by tagName
            tagName.close();
            //free tagName;

            }//grandchild-loop
            //Release any memory consumed by Item grandChild
            grandChild.close();
            //delete grandChild;
    }//child-loop
}//end parent-loop
}
```

I give you the entire file that I am currently working on. There are a lot of errors as I pasted the java code directly into my c++ ide and am simply working at it line by line. Please focus on this line of code:

```
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >::const_iterator got = nodeContainer.find(sectionName.getStringValue());
```

Another thing I should add is that I am rusty at c++ so if there is a better way to accomplish this functionality than a

```
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >
```

I am all ears.

Thank you for reading this far:)

Comment: "I am having a lot of trouble with the complex data structure I am using" -- That is a good acknowledgement. If it is complex to you as author, chances are that it will be even more complex to folks here. You have better chances to solve the problem, either by yourself or by SO folks, by breaking it to smaller manageable sub-problems.

Comment: You're mapping strings to maps of strings to  lists of strings.... What was the complicated part? Expensive to *copy* maybe, but not overtly complicated.

Comment: @Arun thanks I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @WhozCraig I guess by complicated I mean that the syntax is complicated. I had no problem using it in Java.

Comment: @zg303: I've found that when nesting containers, everything magically becomes easier when you typedef the inner container, or maybe make it an actual type.   `typedef unordered_map<string, list<string>> innermap;` and then `unordered_map<string, innermap> nodeContainer;`.  Finally: unordered_map<string, innermap>::const_iterator got = nodeContainer.find...`

Comment: Why do you have a map of strings of maps of strings to lists of strings?  I actually recommend making those into simple classes.

Comment: @MooingDuck I had originally used a typedef but removed it while I was trying to solve the error. I have switched back to using it now that I have gotten rid of my original error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a more specific error message you could break down your problematic line into:

```
const string &keyToTemp(sectionName.getStringValue());
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, list<string> > >::const_iterator got = nodeContainer.find(keyToTemp);
```

Then once that's working the next steps could be along these lines:

With the minimum changes to your code I suppose this is what you're missing:

```
temp = got->second;
```

`find` gives you an iterator to the element and the value_type of a map element is a `pair<KeyType, ValueType>` hence the use of second.
That though will copy the nested map.

Maybe it would be better to use a reference to it instead. In which case the line you asking us to look at would become:

```
 unordered_map<string, list<string> > &temp(nodeContainer.find(sectionName.getStringValue())->second);
```

Comment: Actually, my error is with the find function. I am getting an error that my argument is invalid, even though it is a string which is the same as the key type. I'm really not sure what it is. I am going to take this concept outside of this program and do an example to see whats going on here.

Comment: @zg303 aha, ok I've adjusted my answer to add an suggestion that might help with that. The actual compiler error messages would also help us to understand what the problem is. 

` I am going to take this concept outside of this program...` sounds a good idea...

Comment: Peter, so I created a test program and was able to successfully complete the above operations without an issue. I then tried the suggestion that you added in your edit and found out the real issue here. Its very disappointing, but "sectionName.getStringValue()" does not return a std::string, it returns a zorba::string. Simple casting is not working. I'm giving you the answer on this one because you helped me a lot. From here it looks like I'm going to have to go to the Zorba users group and post this question.

Comment: @zg303 I see that zorba::string has a c_str() member function. Probably that's your best bet for getting to a std::string: `std::string myString(aZorbaString.c_str());` Though maybe just switching to use zorba::string for your map keys might be a better option here.

Comment: I'll give the c_str() function a shot. I have already written a small method to do the conversion but if I can do it in 1 line that would be ideal. As for making a zorba::string the key, I am writting this program so that whoever uses it does not have to mess around with zorba so doing that would defeat the purpose.